# Search two dimensional array for adjacent identical objects

Tags: arrays, algorithm, object, search, multidimensional-array

I have a grid of objects(two dim array) and I want to find all objects adjacent to a chosen object and connected to the adjacent objects and so on and save them in a list of some sort. 
Is there an alogorithm for that? All I could think of was something recursive(I didnt write anything yet, looking for a good start).

Image describing problem(I want to find all red objects adjacent to the red in the circle):

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 2):

Depth first search is exactly what you need. You can use it to find a connected component of the given object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Seems pretty tough though :P